# Enabling UBIFS in U-BOOT

Tags: u-boot

I am attempting to enable UBIFS support into u-boot but have encountered several undefined reference errors when compiling.  In my board configuration, I have enabled the following:

```
#define CONFIG_MTD_DEVICE
#define CONFIG_MTD_PARTITIONS
#define CONFIG_CMD_MTDPARTS
#define CONFIG_CMD_UBI
#define CONFIG_RBTREE
#define CONFIG_CMD_UBIFS
#define CONFIG_LZO
```

And get the following undefined reference errors when compiling:

```
uboot/fs/ubifs/lpt_commit.c:1232: undefined reference to dbg_chk_lpt_free_spc
uboot/fs/ubifs/lpt_commit.c:1235: undefined reference to `dbg_check_ltab'
fs/built-in.o: In function `layout_cnodes':
uboot/fs/ubifs/lpt_commit.c:322: undefined reference to `ubifs_dump_lpt_lebs'
fs/built-in.o: In function `ubifs_add_bud_to_log':
uboot/fs/ubifs/log.c:194: undefined reference to `ubifs_commit_required'
uboot/fs/ubifs/log.c:225: undefined reference to `ubifs_request_bg_commit'
uboot/fs/ubifs/log.c:265: undefined reference to `ubifs_write_node'
fs/built-in.o: In function `ubifs_log_end_commit':
uboot/fs/ubifs/log.c:479: undefined reference to `ubifs_write_master'
fs/built-in.o: In function `do_write_orph_node':
uboot/fs/ubifs/orphan.c:248: undefined reference to `ubifs_write_node'
```

`dbg_chk_lpt_free_spc`, `db_check-ltab`, `ubifs_dump_lpt_lebs`, `ubifs_write_node`, and `ubifs_write_master` are"ifdef'd" out (`#ifndef __UBOOT__` but...obviously `__UBOOT__` is defined).

With a quick grep, `ubifs_commit_required`, `ubifs_request_bg_commit` are completely missing implementations.

Does u-boot not support UBIFS entirely, or is it currently broken? (Using 2016.07 release).  Or am I perhaps missing a step...

Comment: *"Using 2016.07 release"* -- I built U-Boot 2016.03 with the full UBI and UBIFS tools without any issues.

Comment: *"Adding UBIFS support to UBOOT"* is a misleading title.  "Adding support" usually means that you're developing code for a new feature.  All you're trying to do is enable an existing feature.  You also misspelled U-Boot.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the March release in the morning.  And I updated the title.

Comment: The  2016.03 version has the same failures as 07.  I also updated to the newly release 2016.09 version with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UBIFS was indeed broken in the mainline for several architectures.  A proposed patch can be found in the pipemail at http://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2016-September/265474.html, but it hasn't been approved yet.  The patch applied without issues and I can now compile, though whether the filesystem works with it remains to be seen...